# componentDidMount not working on NextJS using a custom _document.js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I'm working on a prototype for a web app and I chose NextJS because I wanted to learn it better, but I realize I'm not using it in the "standard" way. I started from the Next + Material-UI example here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs and all was good.

But now, I'm trying to persist data using `sessionStorage`, and I'm finding it difficult to make this work without being able to use the `componentDidMount` lifecycle event at the page-level. Next's documentation says that projects with a custom _document.js file won't have the `componentDidMount` method client-side. My project uses a custom document file due to Material-UI. It seems like it's there to support server-side rendering of css-in-js frameworks.

If I don't need server-side rendering, is there a way I can keep Material-UI working, but do away with the custom _document.js file so I can use `componentDidMount`?

Comment: Did you get any chance to try my suggestion below? Have you had any difficulties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine using both `sessionStorage` and a custom document.

`componentDidMount` (and any other lifecycle method) is not working **only** for `_document.js` as this is not rendered client side.

`sessionStorage` is part of the `window` so you will be fine using it on any other page/component using the `componentDidMount` lifecycle.

Comment: All code, data, error messages required to reproduce the issue must be embedded in your post as selectable text. Please edit to add a minimum reproducible example to the body of your post. See StackOverflow.com/help/how-to-all for more info.